# Error installing swirl in R ver 3.4.1 32-bit Debian

Tags: r, debian, swirl

I am trying to install swirl in R ver 3.4.1 32-bit on Debian wheezyx and am getting errors.  Please see below:

```
 ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
 Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
 If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
 PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-
 config
 is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
 R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 ERROR: configuration failed for package 'curl'
 * removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl'
 * installing *source* package 'openssl' ...
 ** package 'openssl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums 
 checked
 Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
 Using PKG_CFLAGS=
 Using PKG_LIBS=-lssl -lcrypto
 ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
 Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
 If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
 PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-
 config
 is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
 R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I then tried to  install libcurl4-openssl-dev but get the following error.  I'm not sure what to do next...

```
 > install.packages("libcurl4-openssl-dev")
 Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
 (as 'lib' is unspecified)
 Warning message:
 package 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
 >
```

I tried to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` as a Debian package and this is the output I received.

```
 Setting up dropbear (2014.65-1+deb8u2) ...
Restarting Dropbear SSH server: invoke-rc.d: initscript 
dropbear, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package dropbear (--
configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dropbear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code 
(1)
```

After I run the package the issue still exist.

Comment: After I ran the package the issue still exist.

Answer (score 1):

First try from the terminal:
`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev`

later go back to Rstudio and install swirl package again.